# How to get rid of the space between cards in grid system

Tags: css

[Can someone help me get rid of this space here between the cards.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lHQo.png)

Comment: you need to post the code

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ A link for a link :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide the code, I'll explain it to you.

When you're using grid, it'll base the heights on the largest height there is in each row and place the rest of your elements in that space. This is a logical way of not breaking the flow. You have two options:

- Align your items on the center: `align-items: center;`
- Or, use `display: flex;` and set its flow as vertical with wrapping. It'll automatically place everything and you'll have uniform spacing.